# Check cells for equality

Tags: matlab, equality, cell-array

I am looking for an elegant way to figure out, whether cells in a cell array are totally equal using `equaln`. Here's a toy example:

```
cellarray{1,1,1} = [true, true, true];
cellarray{1,1,2} = [true, true, true];
cellarray{1,1,3} = [true, true, true];

cellarray{1,2,1} = [true, false, false];
cellarray{1,2,2} = [true, true, false];
cellarray{1,2,3} = [false, false, false];
```

I would like to check if the content in cells `cellarray{1,1,:}` can considered to be equal. In reality, the size of the third dimension of this matrix is 1000.

Comment: Equal to what? You expect a 1000*1000 array output with comparisons for every combination of equalities or you just want to know if they are all the same?

Comment: what is the desired output in the example you gave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single call to [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html), passing a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of arguments to test, should be all you need:

```
>> isequal(cellarray{1,1,:})

ans =

  logical

   1

>> isequal(cellarray{1,2,:})

ans =

  logical

   0
```

If you want to treat `NaN` values as equal (they aren't by default) then just use [`isequaln`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequaln.html) instead.

Comment: Ooh. I forgot that `isequal` accepts multiple inputs. Way to go!

Comment: Me too :-( I was of the opinion that isequal accepts only two inputs.
@gnovice Your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
c = cellarray(1,1,:);
allTheSameValues = (nnz(bsxfun(@minus, cell2mat(c), cell2mat(c(1)))) == 0)
```

Comment: `cell2mat` won't work if the contents of all cells are not homogeneous. In the example, this will happen if `cellarray{1,1,3}`

Comment: @LuisMendo: in the user's example the content is actually homogeneous...

Comment: That's my point: it's an _example_. It's not clear whether the contents are _always_ homogeneous. (In fact, if they are it is wasteful to use a cell array)